# undefined method `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag` in Webpacker latest version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, webpacker, actionview

I just upgraded to Webpacker `6.0.0.beta.5` and this error came up.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000fcf8>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this method was removed in the latest Webpacker version because both `javascript_pack_tag` and `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag` did the same thing. Here's the PR https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/2895

To solve this, just rename `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag` to `javascript_pack_tag` in all your files and you should be good.